# Use variable in object call

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying use a variable in an extended method call. I want to substitute an object reference with a variable.

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('sample1.csv')
zones = list(data.columns.values)
for zone in zones:
    print(zone)
    varzone = data.zone.tolist()
    print(varzone)
```

suppose zones is equal to ['name', 'surname']

## I expect it to run as

`varzone = data.name.tolist()`

## rather than:

`varzone = data.zone.tolist()`

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script1.py", line 10, in <module>
    varzone = data.zone.tolist()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4376, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'zone'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is looking for an attribute named `zone` instead of looking for a column by the name stored in `zone`. The correct way would be this:

```
for zone in zones:
    print(zone)
    varzone = data[zone].tolist()
    print(varzone)
```